# File/Image validation in slim framework Request validation

Tags: php, slim, slim-3, respect-validation

I wanted to validate the uploaded image with following parameters like size should not be greater than 100KB, file can be of types [jpg,png,gif].
Please help me to write validation rules for this in Slim framework. I'm using Respect validator.

```
$files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
$validation = $this->validator->validate($request, [
        'name' => v::notEmpty(),
        'description' => v::notEmpty(),
        'logo' => v::size('100KB')->mimetype('image/png,image/png,image/gif')->validate($files['logo']->getClientFilename()),
    ]);
    if ($validation->failed()) {
        $errors = $validation->errors;
        $print_r($errors);
    }
```

This is how I'm using validation rules. Everything works except logo validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something to validate your file size like this

v being the validator you are using

> v::size('1KB')->validate($filename); // Must have at least 1KB size

You can do the following to validate the mine types

> v::mimetype('image/png')->validate('image.png'); // true

Using the Respect validatio, this might be useful http://respect.github.io/Validation/docs/validators.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already went through this but it doesn't helped me because I have an array of supported of mime types.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Have you tried something like this?
`v::mimetype('image/png,image/png,image/gif')->validate('image.png')`

Comment: Remember that the ->validate('image.png'); should be your file you are validating

Comment: thanks for reply I have updated my question summery with my code. Please recheck, Still it's not working for me.

Comment: Just to clarify is it this line that is not working
`'logo' => v::size('100KB')->mimetype('image/png,image/png,image/gif')->validate($files['logo']->getClientFilename()),`

Comment: You can also remove your comma at the end of this line `'logo' => v::size('100KB')->mimetype('image/png,image/png,image/gif')->validate($files['logo']->getClientFilename()),`

Comment: Only this logo rule doesn't work. If I remove this logo validation my validation works properly.  If I use this something like **'logo' => v::size('100KB')->mimetype('image/png,image/png,image/gif')** and upload the image this every time give size and mime typ validation error even I'm uploading correct image. Probably the is with $request while uploading files.

Comment: is the image under 100KB? That is quite small for a image

Comment: Yes my image is under 100KB